# Retrieve the session ID in *agouti.webdriver for Golang

Tags: selenium, go, saucelabs, ginkgo, agouti

I want to use the session id while creating a new WebDriver with Agouti to pass it to SauceLabs for status update.

Commands Used:

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%s@ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub", username, accesskey)
page,err :=agouti.NewPage(url, options)
Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
page.Navigate(`https://qiita.com/login`)
```

I tried to retrieve the session ID from `page.Session()` but the return type is a Bus Interface and result is Session with the `*http.client` variable.

Is there any other alternative to it?, to just retrieve the session id.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know how to parse Output to get Desired Output?

Comment: Yes, I am unable to parse the output or any other alternative to just retrieve the Session ID.

Comment: Just convert the `sessionId` to a string, split it by space, and take the first part.

Comment: I tried following that approach, but I was unable to convert the variable "sessionId" to string, as the return type of page.Session() is *api.Session

Comment: The fact that the logs contain the sessionId as a string, clearly it's possible. What have you tried to convert it to string? Please add that code to your question.

Comment: I used : sessionId, _ = json.Marshal(sessionId)

But i get the error message as "cannot assign [] byte to session id (type *api.Session in multiple assignment"

Answer (score 1):

The page.Session().Bus returns a type *apiSession to extract the session ID. Use of Indirect can help us return the value that *apiSession points to in this case page.Session().Bus from there we can extract the sessionID.

```
sessionBus := reflect.ValueOf(page.Session().Bus)
sessionURL := reflect.Indirect(sessionBus)
sessionField := sessionURL.FieldByName(`SessionURL`)
sessionString := sessionField.String()
sessionSplit := strings.SplitN(sessionString, "/", 7)
sessionID := sessionSplit[len(sessionSplit)-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s", sessionId)[:32])` thanks to Gavin!

Good luck!

Comment: OP's "Desired Output" is the one _without_ `0x1707a60`.

Comment: Ya I got the desired output and output confused. Just updated it @msanford

Comment: Also not correct, this only prints the first 10 characters; OP wants to truncate the _final_ 10 characters.

Comment: Yup. Yours is good. Just want to save as much code as possible!

Comment: I tried with the sessionId[:32] but as its not a string variable cannot slice it I suppose. 

Error: cannot slice sessionId (type *api.Session)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Try `fmt.Println(TrimRight(sessionId, 10))`

Comment: @Brendan It's not a string. You would need something like `fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s", sessionId)[:32])`.

Comment: So try that @Anvesh

Comment: I think we need to first convert the *api.session to string type only then it would work. 

I tried fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s", sessionId)[:32]) but received a weird output - &{%!s(*bus.Client=&{http://amalh

Comment: @Anvesh did you get it working? If so please mark my answer as correct so people in the future can fix this issue!